# CSS "position: sticky" applying horizontal offset in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a sticky table header to the content below it. The structure looks like this:

```
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">
  <div class="sticky-header" id="header_div" style="z-index:1">
    <table class="table" id="header_table">
      <thead id="thead_table">
        <tr>
          <th id="date_header">Date</th>
          ...
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table class="table" id="body_table">
      <thead id="tbody_table">
        <tr>
          <th id="date">Date</th>
          ...
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know the size of my columns or how many columns the table will have so to keep things aligned I have a piece of Javascript that dynamically sets the sizes of all the widths.

The issue I'm having is that in Edge only the sticky property applies a horizontal offset. So in Chrome things look like this:
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epCqC.png)

but in Edge it looks like this:
[Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaIsv.png)

If I toggle the sticky position in Developer Tools it snaps back to center, everything stays aligned, but it obviously loses it's sticky functionality. Can anyone shed some light?

Note: I've seen similar behavior when toggling z-index (i.e. z-index applies a horizontal offset in Edge only) on other pages but I was able to find a work around for those... What on earth is Edge doing?

Comment: I suggest you to provide a simplified example with html and css, it would be much easier to debug

Comment: Yes, the code you post here is supposed to demonstrate the problematic behaviour when run. So since the problem is obviously with the css, we will need to see it!

Comment: I'm seeing this as well - no obvious solution though.